# A global can not be used when making a shared object with bazel

Tags: c, gcc, clang, bazel

I'm facing a compilation error when trying to compile a shared library with bazel, where one of the sources is object file and it is compiled with clang. 
Specifically I get this error

```
`usec_delay' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
error adding symbols: Bad value
```

usec_delay here is a global variable.

Here are the steps I'm performing to create the object file.

1. compile source code to llvm bitcode with clang

   `clang -c -emit-llvm example_src.cc`
2. compile bitcode to assembly

   `llc example_src.bc`
3. compile assembly to object

   `clang -c example_src.s -o example_src.o`

`example_src.o` is then used in bazel BUILD file as a source.

When I compile the same example source code with gcc, then the compilation succeeds. I.e.

```
g++ -S example_src.cc
g++ -c example_src.s
```

I've tried to add `-fPIC` to bazel's `copts` but the problem still exists. And for the case with g++ I don't even need this flag, it works without it.

The part of BUILD file where the compilation is done is following:

```
sim_enclave(
    name = "example.so",
    srcs = [
        "example_enclave.cc",
        "example_src.o",
        "interface_selectors.h",
    ],
    copts = ASYLO_DEFAULT_COPTS,
    deps = [
        "//asylo/platform/primitives",
        "//asylo/util:status_macros",
    ],
)
```

sim_enclave is defined in asylo and is using sgx_enclave rule bellow:

```
def sgx_enclave(
        name,
        config = "@linux_sgx//:enclave_debug_config",
        testonly = 0,
        **kwargs):
    """Build rule for creating SGX enclave shared object files signed for testing.

    The enclave is signed with test key stored in
    @linux_sgx//:enclave_test_private.pem.

    This macro creates two build targets:
      1) name_unsigned.so: cc_binary that builds the unsigned enclave.
      2) name: internal signing rule that (debug) signs name_unsigned.so.

    Args:
      name: The debug-signed enclave target name.
      config: An sgx_enclave_configuration rule.
      testonly: 0 or 1, set to 1 if the target is only used in tests.
      **kwargs: cc_binary arguments.
    Returns:
      string: The name of the signed enclave.
    """
    unsigned_name = _unsigned_enclave_name(name)

    _sgx_unsigned_enclave(
        name = unsigned_name,
        testonly = testonly,
        **kwargs
    )

    kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in ["visibility"]}
    _sgx_debug_sign_enclave(
        name = name,
        unsigned = unsigned_name,
        config = config,
        testonly = testonly,
        **kwargs
    )

    return name
```

The _sgx_unsigned_enclave is defined:

```
def _sgx_unsigned_enclave(
        name,
        **kwargs):
    """Build rule for creating an unsigned SGX enclave shared object file.

    Args:
      name: The enclave target name.
      **kwargs: cc_binary arguments.
    """

    # Append enclave specific arguments.
    kwargs["copts"] = kwargs.get("copts", []) + [
        "-Iexternal/linux_sgx/common/inc/",
        "-fstack-protector",
    ]

    lds_label = "@linux_sgx//:enclave_sim.lds"
    kwargs["features"] = kwargs.get("features", []) + [
        "fully_static_link",
    ]
    kwargs["linkopts"] = kwargs.get("linkopts", []) + [
        "-Wl,-Bstatic",
        "-Wl,-Bsymbolic",
        "-Wl,-pie,-eenclave_entry",
        "-Wl,--defsym,__ImageBase=0",
        "-Wl,--export-dynamic",
        "-Wl,--version-script",
        "$(location %s)" % lds_label,
    ]
    kwargs["linkshared"] = 1
    kwargs["linkstatic"] = 1
    kwargs["deps"] = kwargs.get("deps", []) + [
        lds_label,
        "@linux_sgx//:intel_runtime",
    ]

    # Create rule to build unsigned enclave.
    native.cc_binary(
        name = name,
        **kwargs
    )
```

and _sgx_debug_sign_enclave

```
_sgx_debug_sign_enclave = rule(
    implementation = _sgx_debug_sign_enclave_impl,
    executable = True,
    attrs = {
        "config": attr.label(
            mandatory = True,
            allow_single_file = True,
            providers = [SGXEnclaveConfigInfo],
        ),
        "unsigned": attr.label(allow_single_file = True),
        "_key": attr.label(
            default = Label(
                "@linux_sgx//:enclave_test_private.pem",
            ),
            allow_single_file = True,
        ),
        "_sign_tool": attr.label(
            default = Label("@linux_sgx//:sgx_sign_tool"),
            allow_single_file = True,
            executable = True,
            cfg = "host",
        ),
    },
)
```

The verbose output for bazel build is
[image]

Comment: What's in the BUILD file?

Comment: Also, which Bazel version and what OS?

Comment: @László, the bazel version I'm using is 0.23.1. The part of build file where I'm compiling the shared library is following:
```
sim_enclave(
    name = "example.so",
    srcs = [
        "example_enclave.cc",
        "example_src.o",
        "interface_selectors.h",
    ],
    copts = ASYLO_DEFAULT_COPTS,
    deps = [
        "//asylo/platform/primitives",
        "//asylo/util:status_macros",
    ],
)
```
I'm using the docker container provided by google with Asylo installed in it. And

Comment: @László, I've added the part of BUILD to the original question too, it looks clearer there :)

Comment: Thanks. `sim_enclave` is a custom rule, I don't know how it works, can you paste the definition of it here? Also, run Bazel with `--verbose_failures` to print the command that failed.

Comment: @László, thanks for the reply. I've added the rules used for the compilation and the whole error message to my question. Any idea what is wrong there?

Comment: @László, I've just noticed that if I compile the initial source file to assembly with gcc and then compile it to object file with clang, then I don't have this problem. It seems like compiling to assembly with clang causes the problem.